# Perform filter in controller to search in fields with OR condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I Have a data list say

```
$scope.data = [
  {"id":1,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"kdsingh1002","user":"Hitesh"},
  {"id":2,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"RELEASED","user":"kdsingh1002"},
  {"id":3,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"RELEASED","user":"Hitesh"},
  {"id":4,"buyername":"kdsingh1002","status":"RELEASED","user":"Hitesh"},
  {"id":5,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"DISPUTE","user":"kdsingh1002"}
];
```

Now I applied a filter in HTML as:-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="filterData()">
```

and defined filterData() in controller as:-

```
$scope.filterData = function() {
    $scope.finalData = $filter("filter")($scope.data, { buyername:$scope.searchText, status:$scope.searchText });
};
```

Now what I want is OR of buyername, status i.e in searchText if I entered 'kdsingh1002' then these rows should be returned:-
{"id":1,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"kdsingh1002","user":"Hitesh"},
{"id":4,"buyername":"kdsingh1002","status":"RELEASED","user":"Hitesh"},

**Note:**
I don't want to search in all fields.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about OR condition with `$filter` but you can use `angular.forEach` to filter your records.

Here is [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9A9D9MGG0MkTLlE3R5JP?p=preview)

**filterData** function :

```
$scope.filterData = function() {
    $scope.finalData = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.data,function(data){
        if(data.status.indexOf($scope.searchText) > -1 || data.buyername.indexOf($scope.searchText) > -1){
            $scope.finalData.push(data);   
        }
   })
};
```

Comment: It is now perfectly working. The thing is if I enter partial text say 'kdsingh10' instead of 'kdsingh1002' then it is returning null unless and untill it gets complete matching string i.e. 'kdsingh1002'

Comment: Is there something like 'like' operator ?

Comment: Its simple use `.startswith()`, I updated my plunker and answer, please check again.

Comment: And what if entered 'singh10' ?
I want searching in the way $filter works but with OR condition.

Comment: then use `indexOf($scope.searchText) >  -1` again updated plunker, pls check.

Comment: One more thing I found is use of .includes()