# Angularjs filter object parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just get stuck with my code when I am trying to make a filter for my ng repeat div element
I am trying to use one input

```
<input type="text" class="search_input" ng-model="search">
```

But in filter I would like to use that search parameter for username and user id.

```
<div  ng-repeat="customer in userList | filter : {customer.username : search,  customer.user_id : search}">
```

So it should show me te correct user with that username or ID what I put to input. How to make it? I am new in angular and I couldn't find for it till now some answers.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346260/perform-filter-in-controller-to-search-in-fields-with-or-condition/32346758#32346758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom filter, take a look at this answer for further information:

[AngularJS filter on multiple values of one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736518/angularjs-filter-on-multiple-values-of-one-field)

I would comment this, but my rep is too low

Answer (score 0):

create a function in your controller which will return you true/false depending upon your filter criteria :

```
$scope.fnFilter = function(customer){
    return customer.username === $scope.search || customer.user_id === $scope.search;
};
```

use it in your html as :

```
<div  ng-repeat="customer in userList | filter : fnFilter">
```